# Is this a tautological argument?

Tags: logic, fake-proofs

Assume $A$ is true, and that $A$ implies $B$. If I then can prove that if $A$ implies $B$, then $B$ implies $A$, have I then proved that $A$ is true (without the need to assume that $A$ is true in the first place)?

Comment: Wait, what? What statements do you have and what do you want to prove, exactly? All statements except $A$ are true when $A$ and $B$ are both false.

Comment: If I understand your vague description correctly, you've assumed that A is true, and then used it in order to eventually prove that A is true. In that case, no, you haven't proved that A is true without assuming it in the first place.

Comment: The underlying problem that I am trying approach is: "If the non-trivial Riemann zeta zeros have real part $1/2$ then their imaginary parts must be of this form. And if the imaginary parts of the Riemann zeta zeros are of this form then their real part must be $1/2$.

But I am still missing the effective lower bound for gaps between the Riemann zeta zeros, and there is trouble with non-fitting values of the complex argument of a complex number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 
$$A \implies B \\
(A \implies B) \implies (B \implies A)$$
the only possible conclusion is that 
$$ A \iff B$$
So, $A$ and $B$ are either both true or both false.